# Questions about LaTeX: when should I post in TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange vs Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been wanting to ask questions about how to make some specific kinds of table in [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). Eventually I decided to ask my question in Stack Overflow. But should I use Stack Overflow or *[TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

I found similar questions on both sites (I even tried to flag a couple as duplicates of each other, which failed because they're in different sites). Stack Overflow seemed to have more questions and more answers, so I decided to ask there. But later I saw a discussion on Meta suggesting that all questions about pure Tex should be moved to *TeX - LaTeX* and that they are answered faster there. So what's the general guideline here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to be clear: it is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on more than one site. And there is not necessarily a single correct site for a question.

For example, I can imagine a single TeX-related question to be simultaneously on-topic on Ask Ubuntu, Unix.SE, SuperUser, Stack Overflow, and TeX.

If a question is on-topic on multiple sites, the site on which to post the question depends on:

- Where the experts are and
- what kinds of answers you are looking for.

In the case of TeX, I think there is a very clear "best" site, namely the TeX site.

However, there are other topics where the decision is not that clear, and might depend on what kind of answer you are looking for. For example, shell scripting questions typically get very simple "Here's the code you were asking for" answers on Super User, whereas on Unix.SE, answers might delve into the various historic incompatibilities between shells, and on Stack Overflow, you might get a concise solution using the latest modern shell features.

And, this might be an unpopular opinion, I believe, you *can* ask a question on multiple sites simultaneously, provided you *specifically tailor the question to each site's audience*. See the last paragraph of the canonical answer to [*Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/2988) on Meta.SE.

Comment: That's right, each site is striving to become a compendium of Q&A on its respective scope. I don't want to see questions on LaTeX on Stack Overflow closed citing this meta question.

Answer (score 45):

LaTeX questions belong on Tex.SE (in about 99.999999% of the cases I've observed).  They only existed here because, at the time, there was no Tex.SE.

Comment: OK, well now I have to ask what the 0.000001% of cases were.

Comment: @TylerH:  Someone using a programming language to automate generating TeX-compatible documents, or something that generates TeX documents through code ([like PyX](https://pyx-project.org/))?

Comment: Qualifying the answer... unless you're implementing a TeX-related program that's not itself written in (LaTeX); that might belong on SO. Otherwise

Comment: So, from the 22.000.000 questions asked, 0.22 questions were actually on-topic here. That's good to know.

Comment: Discounting sampling statistics, 99.999999% would imply at least 100 million LaTeX questions have been observed.

Comment: Does the same argument apply to [tag:mathematica] questions?

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ: I'd be *very* hesitant with a CAS. I would think that those could go on Math.SE but it's been over a decade since I cared enough about Mathematica to know if it's on topic there. I can't really think of examples where it'd be on topic here, though.

Comment: There's a separate [mathematica.se] site

Comment: Unfortunately there’s a high-ranking Stack Overflow LaTeX user who has some beef with the tex.SE site, and therefore answers questions on Stack Overflow instead of doing the correct thing, and voting to migrate questions. Since there’s also very little activity in this tag on Stack Overflow, the end result is that very few questions get migrated. Usually TeX questions on SO only have a single vote to migrate them — mine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There is no way to migrate questions to the Tex SE by community votes. The company does not understand, why would it be useful, and most of the close voters does not know that the Tex SE exists. There is also an unsaid and unexplainable wish from the side of the company to minimize the from-SO post migrations. Mods can migrate, users can not. But if a mod migrates, he also takes part in the reponsibility (if the target site dislikes the content, it will be the mods fault), so they don't really like to do that.

Comment: @peterh “There is no way to migrate questions to the Tex SE by community votes” —  Uh, that is completely wrong. There *is* a way to migrate posts by community vote, it just requires three users vote to close the question with the close reason “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network”. This exists, and it works. From your subsequent comments it’s obvious that you’re aware of this, so I don’t understand how you could have knowingly made the false statement in your first comment in good faith.

Comment: _"The company does not understand, why would it be useful, and most of the close voters does not know that the Tex SE exists. There is also an unsaid and unexplainable wish from the side of the company to minimize the from-SO post migrations."_ This is demonstrably false. Furthermore, you're claiming the mods try not to take responsibility for their actions, while that's basically the majority of the job description.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That is right, there is a community migration path to the Tex SE. Mea culpa. However, it is still very hard to collect the 3 migration close votes, and all of them to the Tex SE.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Voting to migrate is just a huge wast of everyone's time, I tried it when I first came to SO, but they simply age away -- I have hundreds of such flags https://i.stack.imgur.com/akCmI.png

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for your comment. I have to admit that I assumed your inaction with regards to migration, which I’ve repeatedly observed, was for bad reasons. Your comment makes it clear that my assumption was utterly wrong. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Accepted :) My current view about migration is a bit similar to the answer by @ JörgWMittag Posts should be where they get answers. If a post got an answer here, there is no need to migrate it. If I think the post is more likely to get an answer at tex.se, migration is, also most likely futile, the way to go (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628666/pdflatex-does-not-compile-on-fresh-texlive-2021-install). Voting to migrate those, would only increase the backlog in the review queues. However one important point for me: the post needs to have sufficient quality.

Comment: There is no gain from migrating low quality posts which lack a mwe or other necessary information. That there are often migration votes on such low quality post is very problematic. I would like to vote to close them, but if others vote to migrate them, then my name would be shown as one of the users who migrated the post. As I don't want to be seen as someone to migrate low quality posts, I don't vote to close and rather leave such low quality posts around.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz These are all good points, and going forward I will strive to not cast migration votes without being sure that the post would actually be of high enough quality (in the past I’ve often voted reflexively without considering post quality, only topic).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @KonradRudolph :-) The reality is that "the community" has an allergy to the question migrations and they always know, why a post should not be migrated. However, fact is that moving a post to a correct site is always better then leaving it where it does not belong to. A possible reason is that at the Stack Exchange, 1 site = 1 (ms sql) database, and moving records between databases is problematic for them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1550340/closed-as-offtopic-score-2) are the well received, but offtopic closed questions. Check the query and decide yourself, what should have been done to them.

Comment: _"A possible reason is that at the Stack Exchange, 1 site = 1 (ms sql) database, and moving records between databases is problematic for them."_ There is tooling to migrate questions between sites, and moderators do this _all the time_... Please provide a source that backs up your claims that migrations are so difficult, and that SE / "the community" detests migrations.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have none, except what I learnt here in the past nearly decade. I wish to support it also with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1550340/closed-as-offtopic-score-2), showing the best, never migrated, but obviously offtopic posts. There is yet another problem, and this is your ongoing crusade against me. I understand that there is the covid and likely an economical crisis will follow it, but... I can not understand why you do not have any better to do than stalking me.

Comment: @peterh: Sort that query by date. That's 1 or 2 questions per day. Can you make the same query for questions that _do_ get migrated? A single data point doesn't prove a trend.

Comment: @Cerbrus A real number can not be said easily - the close reason exists only in the PostHistory table, but it does not contain data about deleted posts. There are various ways to circumvent this problem, the simplest is using 10k+ with random sampling. Problem is that any random hugely decreases the strength of the arguments in a mainly hostile scenario. You can see [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1550701) the stat of the offtopic closed, but not yet deleted questions. I doubt if it says anything. We need the close reason data of the deleted questions in the SEDE.

Comment: So, you can't provide a comparative dataset... Then that query you did link is pretty meaningless if we have nothing to compare it to.

Comment: @peterh: I had answered previously that community members should gain some form of privilege (vote weight) associated with migration to a site they are a trusted user on (or just have high reputation); see [What privilege should 30k users get?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252705/168244). It would help cross-network communities push posts where they belong.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: I've vote-to-close with a migration path to [tex.se] almost always. However, migration only occurs if the closure votes agree (that is, all vote to migrate). If some vote to close because of missing details, migration doesn't occur AFAIK, and the votes *for* migration are merely reported as a vote for closure ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30712402), since I vote to migrate 99.9% of the time, yet this just put me down as a vote-to-close with, I think, the original reason for closure suggested by you). Hence reluctance to vote for migration.

Comment: @Werner Ok, in the other direction that's still a problem: one can't vote to migrate a perfectly fine on-topic question without the risk that one will be shown as close voter, see e.g. the discussion at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570341/latex-how-to-get-correct-size-position-of-nested-brackets-around-fractions#comment1437353_570341 Conclusion: migration system is simply completely broken.

Comment: @Cerbrus [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1553220) is the count of the offtopic-closed, but not deleted questions of the site. Their count is now 149608. The count of the offtopic-closed, but deleted questions is harder to count, as the close reason is not available in the SEDE for deleted questions. But there is a way to circumvent it. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1539761) is a random sample of the deleted questions. I found 8 offtopic-closed questions in this sample, what is 8%.

Comment: @Cerbrus The total count of the deleted questions, as you can see [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1553226), is 9421581 now. That makes a reasonable estimate to the offtopic-closed, deleted questions to about 750000. These two add to about 900 000. At the time, as the company did not start to graduate sites so easily than today, the median question count at the site graduation was about 10000. The result is that the offtopic-closed questions could have created 90 (!!!) new SE sites, enough big to graduate even on the old, strict graduation rules.

Comment: @Cerbrus As a comparison, currently the SE site network has about 160 sites (most of them far below 10000 questions and already many years old).

Comment: So, out of a sample of _100_ deleted questions (which is arguably an insignificant sample size), _8_ are closed as off-topic. From that you're making an broad estimate, disregarding that question migration is a relatively new feature in the history of Stack Exchange. The resulting total could could well be an order of magnitude larger or smaller, depending on whether you found 2 or 20 questions. Now, you claim that all these migrated questions _could_ have created new sites. The problem is that those new sites had no way of existing at the time of migration, a bit of a chicken / egg prooblem.

Comment: TL;DR, you're making quite a few assumptions, and deriving statistics to back your opinion out of those, @peterh. ___If___ any of these numbers were correct, you might have a point that we need a few more sites, but __90__ of'm? Heck no.

Comment: @Cerbrus Not insignificant, because it is random sample. But you can create a much bigger sample, or create another random sample with a different random seed, this query is well parametrizable. Question migrations existed already at 2014, but probably much more earlier - I know this because I lobbied for them on the MSO already at the time. And I hit the same walls, than now. And yes, if the long-term well-being (and growth) of this so fruitful-looking site model is important for us, then yes, the growth should be our top concern.

Comment: A random sample is only accurate when taken form a _large_ sample, @peterh. __100__ questions is absolutely nothing in the scale of SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus Note also, the growth of the SO seems to be in a slow decrease since 2014. ([Proof](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/649165)). Meanwhile, the size of the internet roughly doubled around it.

Comment: Get _one_ accredited data analist to tell me that a random sample of 100 questions out of 71 __million__ is significant and I'll eat my words, @peterh.

Answer (score 20):

The [answer of Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415684/) is right, LaTeX questions are best asked on TeX.SE.

We (I'm a regular at TeX.SE) also welcome questions on generating LaTeX code from other programming languages, such as [`pylatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pylatex) for Python and [`knitr`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knitr) for R, or any program or tool that has "export to LaTeX" functionality like gnuplot or Matlab etc.

One thing that is *not* on-topic on TeX.SE is MathJax and KaTeX (both are javascript libraries to display mathematics with a syntax borrowed from LaTeX). Questions about that should be asked on SO.

Comment: I'm only an occasional user of [latex] or Tex.SE, so I don't know if your answer represents consensus in those groups, but if it does, perhaps the tag description for [latex] on SO should be updated to reflect it.

Comment: @user2554330 which part of the tag excerpt (or wiki) do you think needs updating specifically? Are you referring to my remark on MathJax and KaTeX?

Comment: Yes, mainly the MathJax and KaTeX part.  You might expand on what kinds of knitr and pylatex questions are welcome on TeX.SE as well.